# Why do we use indicative in "Se me ocurre que tal vez estuvieron juntos (...), pero según ellos 'eso sería imposible'?

Tags: subjuntivo, indicativa

I found this excerpt from "El Cuaderno de Maya", by Isabel Allende:

> Por una de esas casualidades novelescas, él terminó su visita a Chile el mismo día de 1974 en que ella salió con su hijo a Canadá. Se me ocurre que tal vez estuvieron juntos en el aeropuerto esperando sus respectivos vuelos, sin conocerse, pero según ellos **eso sería imposible**, porque él se habría fijado en aquella bella mujer y ella también lo habría visto, porque un negro llamaba la atención en el Chile de entonces, especialmente uno tan alto y apuesto como mi Popo.

This seems like the proper place to use the subjunctive "hubiera sido impossible". Is there any significance or reason to use the indicative here? Does indicative mean that it's more definite that the hypothetical event didn't happen maybe? (I'm guessing. I haven't read in a grammar book that an imagined event shouldn't be in the subjunctive for particular reasons.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form of the verb being used here is the conditional.  The conditional exists in an odd space modally, and while it is most commonly placed in the indicative, that classification is by no means absolute.  To wit:

> Nueva Gramática de la lengua española (2009)
>   **23.15a** Es tradicional la polémica en torno a si el condicional (*cantaría*) es un tiempo del indicativo o un modo verbal.  Se suele aceptar hoy la primera opción, sobre todo porque el condicional aparece en entornos sintácticos en los que se selecciona el modo indicativo *(*Prometió que iría)* y se rechaza en los que seleccionan el subjuntivo: *Deseamos que {*irían ~fueran} ustedes*.  Aun así, es oportuno recordar que el condicional no expresa solo situaciones orientadas en relación con el momento del habla o con otro punto que se tome como eje, sino también contenidos no factuales (§25.1c) supeditados a situaciones hipotéticas, lo que se deduce de su orientación prospectiva.  Se ha señalado que el hecho de que las oraciones formadas con este tiempo sean proposiciones supeditadas a otras impide otorgarles con nitidez un valor de verdad, más claramente incluso que a las construidas en futuro.

Furthermore, many speakers —in pretty much every region and especially in spoken Spanish— are known to swap out the conditional in favor of the imperfect indicative or subjunctive and perhaps to your ear this is what you're hearing.

But strictly speaking, what we have are a series of independent clauses:

```
Se me ocurre que …
    PERO
sería imposible
    PORQUE
él se habría…
    Y
ella también…
    PORQUE
un negro llamaba…
```

Independent clauses in modern Spanish generally reject the subjunctive.

There are, ultimately, three justifications we have here specifically for the use of *sería* as opposed to *<sup>fue</sup>/<sub>era</sub>* (note that the compound forms *<sup>hubo</sup>/<sub>había</sub> sido* can't really be used, because we're not discussing the past of the past).

1. There is an elided hypothetical.  Note that she writes "se me ocurre que *tal vez* estuvieron juntos".  That means that the rest of this discussion is only a possibility (that is, we should attach a "probablemente" to the rest of the narration).  Thus, when we read "eso sería imposible", we should read an implied "eso sería imposible *si fuese que estuvieron juntos*".  Thus we have an a typical conditional+past subjunctive counter factual construction.
2. Though the forms *<sup>fue</sup>/<sub>era</sub>* would work just fine, it is common enough to substitute with the conditional, especially to give the sense of "in the end":

   > **23.15r** El uso de *cantaría* por *canté* en contextos retrospectivos […] se ha llamado factual, pero podría denominarse *narrativo* […] En esas oraciones no se introducen situaciones hipotéticas, sino hechos acaecidos.  Al igual que sucede con el imperfecto narrativo, el condicional que se le asimila se usa sobre todo en la lengua literaria, en la periodística y en otros registros cultos de la lengua escrita
3. To give a sense of *it had to've been* or *it must've been*.  Compare the difference between a present narration having *es imposible* vs. *será imposible*.

And being the skilled writer that she is, the author's intent may very well have been to allude to several of those meanings simultaneously.

Comment: I tried to up vote twice but it's not allowed :)